# MYSQL innerjoin with limit?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, limit

I have two tables, one of the holds tools, the other one holds the tools history like location and who has it. I need to run a search question on this tables and have tried this

```
SELECT tblmaskin.* 
FROM `tblmaskin` 
INNER JOIN tblmaskinhistorik ON tblmaskin.maskinId=tblmaskinhistorik.maskinId 
WHERE tblmaskin.maskin='".$_POST['sok']."' 
OR tblmaskinhistorik.var='".$_POST['sok']."'
 OR  tblmaskinhistorik.anvandarnamn='".$_POST['sok']."'
```

But the problem is that I only want to search the last inserted row for that tool in the history table. When you do a search for a tool by place for example you only want to get the tool that is there now.

Is there a way to do that?

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8906/1/0).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600527/accessing-last-inserted-row-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A side note: It looks you're using PHP and you're not using prepared statement, check out [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)*.

There's actually an [article in official MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) about this + similar thing was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678250/1149736) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666519/1149736).

You need to run a sub-query to fetch id of the "*latest*" history record (assuming record with max id is the right one) and then use that id to fetch correct record.

*Note: I've replaced your inlined php variables with [PDO's named placeholders](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-952)*

```
SELECT tblmaskin.* 
FROM `tblmaskin` 
-- Select record from tblmaskinhistorik with the highest id
INNER JOIN (SELECT maskinId, MAX(maskinhistId) AS maxid
           FROM tblmaskinhistorik
           GROUP BY maskinId) AS t_max
    ON t_max.maskinId = tblmaskin.maskinId
-- Joining whole row
INNER JOIN tblmaskinhistorik ON t_max.maxid=tblmaskinhistorik.maskinhistId
WHERE tblmaskin.maskin=:sok 
    OR tblmaskinhistorik.var=:sok
    OR tblmaskinhistorik.anvandarnamn=:sok
```

Run `EXPLAIN` on the query to ensure that it's working efficiently.

Comment: Not working, if i do a search on a user tblmaskinhistorik.anvandarnamn i don't get all the tools that user have right now and i also get other users tools. Thanx for trying i might just cheat and add two fields in the tool table that contains the last user and place. But it really irritates me I hate giving up.

Comment: @user2978137 it should be `INNER JOIN tblmaskinhistorik ON t_max.maxid=tblmaskinhistorik.maskinhistId` (wrong id checked), try it out; I'm adding sqlfiddle example to your question. Also please add expected results.

Answer (score -1):

insert `limit 1 order by 'your field' desc` with your query

Comment: why it's negatively marked? I am confused what's wrong with it?

Comment: OP wants to fetch one line for each tool not one line in general.